# How to add animated images in a mobile app

Tags: image, flutter, animation, mobile

I am working on a mobile app and need some animated images. What is the best way to add these?

At first I thought of GIF's but according to my illustrator, this results in bad color transitions. He suggests using video's. But these are way larger and only MOV supports transparent backgrounds which is even larger.

What is the common practice in this usecase?

I use flutter to build the app but that should not make a difference I think.

Comment: Have you tried https://rive.app, https://pub.dev/packages/rive?

Comment: No, had never heard of it before, it's awesome :O. I don't think the illustrator uses the it though...

Comment: I think it's easy to use. Don't have any experience in animation, but I can create simple icon animations using rive. Maybe your illustrator can easily adapt, only if you're not in hurry.